# Material UI Autocomplete RenderTags not working with React Final Form mutator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
          <Autocomplete
              multiple
              id="tags-filled"
              options={tags} 
              freeSolo
              onChange={handleTagChange}
              renderTags={(value: string[], getTagProps) => {
                value.map((option: string, index: number) => {
                  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-keyy
                  <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />;
                  if (value !== values.metadata.keywordTags) {
                    setValue('metadata.keywordTags', value);
                  }
                });
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  name={'metadata.keywordTags'}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Keyword tags (optional)"
                />
              )}
            />
```

The onChange sets the different tags in an array and setValue() inside of the render is a mutator that adds the string array of the tags to the data.

When the component is being used, it correctly stores the array of tags in the data. [Only issue is that the chip doesn't show up](https://i.imgur.com/0FFryj9.png)

**What I tried:**

```
         <Autocomplete
              multiple
              id="tags-filled"
              options={tags}
              freeSolo
              onChange={handleTagChange}
              renderTags={(value: string[], getTagProps) =>
                value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
                  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
                  <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
                ))
              }
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  name={'metadata.keywordTags'}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Keyword tags (optional)"
                />
              )}
            />
```

As you can see, I modified the renderTags a bit (removed some curly braces), and [now the chips work](https://i.imgur.com/FH2y2fz.png).

However, [only the last tag is stored into the data](https://i.imgur.com/I5c64fm.png)

I'm assuming this is because of the name={'metadata.keywordTags'} in the TextField component? What can I do to show the chips and get the correct array of tags stored in the data?

Comment: You don't set values in `renderTags`, you set it in `handleChange`. Check the MUI docs.

Comment: Thank you, wish I can somehow give you an upvote. That fixed it for me